# how to convert string values of an array to integer in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am not being able to convert the string value of an array (e.g. `score:["1", "0"]`) into an Integer in Neo4j.

I have tried:

```
MATCH (n:Game {game_id:"1"})
RETURN toInteger(n.score[0])
```

This query returns a `null` value as a result.

Comment: Are you sure that the node has the expected `score` property value? What is the return value of `MATCH (n:Game {game_id:"1"}) RETURN n.score`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your query, but it works fine for me. This is my example data set:

```
CREATE (n:Game {game_id:"1", score:["1","0"]})
```

This is the query:

```
MATCH (n:Game {game_id:"1"})
RETURN toInteger(n.score[0])
```

And it returns:

```
╒═══════════════════════╕
│"toInteger(n.score[0])"│
╞═══════════════════════╡
│1                      │
└───────────────────────┘
```